# Is the close vote queue backlogged?

Tags: discussion, review, closing, statistics

Pretty much every day I go through all of my 20 close vote reviews. So I am wondering:

- How many items are in the close vote queue?
- How many items have been in the queue over the past few weeks or months?
- Is the rate that items enter the queue greater than the rate that users are currently reviewing them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can find the current number of items in every queue by opening the [Review page](https://math.stackexchange.com/review) in the private/incognito mode of your browser, or in another browser where you are not logged in.
2. The size of the queue as a function of time is [here](https://goo.gl/tb7sdD); beginning at the end of September. My script records the size every 4 hours.
3. This is answered by 2: it varies. The curve has large swings both up and down. On average, it does have an upward trend.

Comment: That's cool. It may be too much to ask, but is it possible to get an average "time to service" for individual items? Maybe the volume of close votes just increased over time and so the backlog naturally increases even with a constant time to service.

Comment: This can be obtained from Data Explorer, but the [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/199802/evolution-of-review-time-over-time) I found gives implausibly large numbers. It's either buggy, or should use median instead of average, or something else. Poking around in [close history](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?page=3) I see that the questions that got closed took about 2-4 hours.

Comment: It indeed seems bugged. The numbers from [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/cs/query/199807/suggested-edit-weekly-statistics) sound more plausible (and are different from the values presented in the linked query)... Maybe it's something about time-to-close vs. time-to-delete...